# message queuing + ajax not firing

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have created a php class which is pretty expensive and needs to process a lot of request on an admin page. For this reason I'm trying to using jquery queing + ajax calls to batch process the requests however the whole javascript is not firing and I don't understand why. I'm more of a PHP expert nog so much js or jQuery.

The code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  window.queue = $.jqmq({
    // Queue items will be processed every 250 milliseconds.
    delay: 500,
    // Process queue items one-at-a-time.
    batch: 10,
    // For each queue item, execute this function.
    callback: function (model, apit) {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'script.php',
        type: "post",
        cache: false,
        data: "model=" + model + "&api=" + apit,
        success: function (data) {
          $(".error_msg p").append(data);
        }
      },
      // When the queue completes naturally, execute this function.
      complete: function () {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'script.php',
          type: "post",
          cache: false,
          data: "cleanup=1",
          success: function (data) {
            $(".error_msg p").append(data);
          }
          $('.error_msg p').append('<br /><span class="done">Queue done<\/span>');
        }
        });
      //the next line is repeated a couple hundred times with different values  
      queue.add('arg1', 'arg2'); queue.add('arg1', 'arg2');
      });
</script>
```

This code is located in the body.
Scripts included (in the head) are:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ba-jqmq.js"></script>
```

I've checked with TamperData FF plugin and the ajax posts to script.php are just not firing and I have no idea why..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [jqmq documents](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-message-queuing/docs/files/jquery-ba-jqmq-js.html#jQuery.jqmq) it says that the callback method accepts a single argument. You're trying to send more. The second parameter of the add method is for priority and can only be a boolean.

```
queueObj.add( item [, priority ] );
```

You should add your arguments as an array or an object.

I've created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6tdZt/2/) and it seems to be working fine.

UPDATE:
Also, I believe simultaneous ajax request are limited to 3 or 4, so you won't be able to have batches of 10.

Comment: thanks! I missed that from the docs.. going to try it tomorrow as its 4.20am right now :) but looks very promising to solve my problem

Comment: ok so your answer is of course correct however it wasn't the only problem. I remember the reason why I don't like JS very much..

The code was missing a bunch of closing tags such as }) and ; in several places and JS of course doesn't really tell you this; hey there is something missing on line xx like PHP does :S

Comment: Most IDE will warn you on syntax errors and errors like a missing closing bracket will show in the browsers console. The ';' is optional in javascript though.